Using Flask: telegram.error.NetworkError: Unknown error in HTTP implementation: RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
I use Flask to process an HTTP request and send a message using a telegram bot. The first time the message is processed normally and returns a 200 response
python3[322907]: INFO:httpx:HTTP Request: POST https://api.telegram.org/bot3123123:Aasfasfasf_asfasfY/sendMessage "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
python3[322907]: INFO:root:Port 10000 has been blocked for user 619977240.
python3[322907]: INFO:root:Port 10000 has been blocked
INFO:werkzeug:37.223.126.21 - - [25/Jun/2024 13:24:25] "POST /block_port HTTP/1.1" 200 -

, but the second time an error occurs
python3[322907]: telegram.error.NetworkError: Unknown error in HTTP implementation: RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
python3[322907]: INFO:werkzeug:37.223.126.21 - - [25/Jun/2024 13:24:40] "POST /block_port HTTP/1.1" 500 -  

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import logging
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import telegram
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from database_central import find_user_by_port

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
bot = telegram.Bot(token=os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN"))

async def send_blocked_message(user_id, port):
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Разблокировать", callback_data='unlock')]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='Ваш ключ заблокирован из-за подозрительной активности. Если Вы считаете что это ошибка, то нажмите кнопку ниже.', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    logging.info(f"Port {port} has been blocked for user {user_id}.")

@app.route('/block_port', methods=['POST'])
async def block_port():
    port = request.form.get('port')
    if port:
        user_id = find_user_by_port(port)
        if user_id:
            await send_blocked_message(user_id, port)      <------ Error here
            logging.info(f"Port {port} has been blocked")
            return jsonify({'message': f'Port {port} has been blocked for user {user_id}.'}), 200
        else:
            logging.info(f"Port {port} has been blocked, but no user found.")
            return jsonify({'message': f'Port {port} has been blocked, but no user found.'}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Port not provided.'}), 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)  

I used regular Flask and asynchronous (pip install flask[async]), but nothing helped. I also used asyncio, but nothing helped either. If you remove the await send_blocked_message(user_id, port) function call, then everything works fine.

The issue you are encountering with the "Event loop is closed" error is related to how asyncio event loops are managed in your Flask application. Flask is traditionally synchronous, but you are using asynchronous functions with await which require proper event loop management.
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import logging
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import telegram
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.error import NetworkError
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
bot = telegram.Bot(token=os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN"))

async def send_blocked_message(user_id, port):
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Разблокировать", callback_data='unlock')]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='Ваш ключ заблокирован из-за подозрительной активности. Если Вы считаете что это ошибка, то нажмите кнопку ниже.', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    logging.info(f"Port {port} has been blocked for user {user_id}.")

def run_async(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        if loop.is_closed():
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        return loop.run_until_complete(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper

@app.route('/block_port', methods=['POST'])
@run_async
async def block_port():
    port = request.form.get('port')
    if port:
        user_id = find_user_by_port(port)
        if user_id:
            await send_blocked_message(user_id, port)      # <------ Error should be resolved here
            logging.info(f"Port {port} has been blocked")
            return jsonify({'message': f'Port {port} has been blocked for user {user_id}.'}), 200
        else:
            logging.info(f"Port {port} has been blocked, but no user found.")
            return jsonify({'message': f'Port {port} has been blocked, but no user found.'}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Port not provided.'}), 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)

Key Changes:
Imported asyncio and nest_asyncio: This helps manage the event loop properly and allows nesting of event loops.
Added run_async decorator: This ensures the async function runs within a proper event loop context.
Applied nest_asyncio.apply(): This allows the event loop to be reused within the same context.
This setup should prevent the "Event loop is closed" error and allow your Flask app to handle asynchronous requests correctly.

Sounds like ChatGPT this

Thanks, it works much better, but sometimes another error occurs "telegram.error.NetworkError: Unknown error in HTTP implementation: RuntimeError('<asyncio.locks.Event object at 0x7f444b947f40 [unset]> is bound to a different event loop')
"
